# Excluir elemento de selector-JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Me gustaría aplicar una función que deshabilite el `click` (la cual encontré por aquí) a varios `<div>`, exceptuando los `<a>` con la clase `.ellipsis_inline` que están dentro de los mismos.

Pero al final o me bloquea todo o no me bloquea nada.

**Mi selector**

```
 $('.span6.record-cell > :not(.ellipsis_inline)').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false;
 });
```

**Estructura de Divs**

```
<div class="span6 record-cell" data-type="relate" data-name="tct_persona1_c">
<div class="record-label" data-name="tct_persona1_c">
    Cuenta 1
</div>
<span class="normal index" data-fieldname="tct_persona1_c" data-index="">
    <span sfuuid="1169" class="detail">
        <a class="ellipsis_inline" data-placement="bottom" title="" href="#Accounts/b7a86eb2-a490-11e8-b856-00155da06f04" data-original-title="PEPE PROBLEMAS">PEPE PROBLEMAS</a>
    </span>
</span>
<span class="record-edit-link-wrapper" data-name="tct_persona1_c" data-wrapper="edit" tabindex="-1">
    <a class="record-edit-link btn btn-invisible" data-type="relate" data-name="tct_persona1_c"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
</span>
<span class="record-lock-link-wrapper hide" data-name="tct_persona1_c">
    <a class="record-lock-link btn btn-invisible" data-type="relate" data-name="tct_persona1_c">
        <i class="fa fa-lock" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="Este campo está bloqueado porque está implicado en un proceso en ejecución." data-placement="right"></i>
    </a>
</span></div>
```

Comment: Hola Jess182, deberías añadir una descripción de lo que hayas intentado para que sirva de referencia a los usuarios. Los elementos `div` no tienen ninguna acción asociada por defecto cuando se pulsa sobre ellos, por lo que no termina de quedar claro a qué te refieres con deshabilitar el click a varios `div`.

Comment: Si, olvide poner mi selector, pero ya lo he agregado, gracias, y con respecto a los div, estoy trabajando sobre SugarCRM, y quiero desahabilitar los div de una vista, muchos de esos divs, tienen contenido diferente, pero quiero mantener los "links" habilitados, y la funcion que encontré me los deshabilita.

Saludos

Comment: Sólo por curiosidad, por qué quieres deshabilitar los clicks en los elementos padre de esos links? O entendí mal y lo que quieres es deshabilitar el click no en el contenedor sino en otros elementos <a> ?

Comment: Otra observación: el Chevrón indica que apuntas a un hijo directo del elemento `.padre > .hijo` En tu caso el link está dentro de detail, que a su vez está dentro de normal, de modo que no es un hijo directo. Vendría siendo un bisnieto

Comment: si amnadiel, como tal tengo varios divs con diferente contenido,todos con la clase .span6 record-cell, con lo cual, quiero deshabilitar todos, a excepcion de los que tienen links, y en efecto no logro llegar hasta el bisnieto, mi pregunta de manera mas sencilla es como hago un not del bisnieto....

Answer (score 1):

`$('.span6.record-cell').not('.ellipsis_inline').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     return false;
 });`

Comment: Tambien lo he intentado asi Pepe y no me ha funcionado